# Regex Matching Issue

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to validate an input of format "AB1234" where first two characters must be Alpha (A-Z) and remaining must be numbers. 
My current regex is validating the input "AB123A" which is incorrect. What is missing my current regex?

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{1,6}
```

Comment: ^[A-Z]{2}\d{1,6}$ should work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing `$` which specifies the end of the string

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{1,6}$
```

---

`^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{1,6}` without `$` matches `AB123A` since you are not specifying any `end` to that string..

It matches `AB123` within `AB123A`

Answer (score 2):

You are missing a $ at the end:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{1,6}$
```

The $ specifies the end of the string being tested.

Answer (score 0):

Add a $ dollar to the end of your regexp:

```
^[a-zA-Z]{2}\d{1,6}$
```

otherwise it matches the "AB123" part of "AB123A".